# how to create a screen session within an existing screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

Case scenario:

When I open my terminal, screen starts automatically. This is useful because I often need multiple screens locally within the same terminal.

However, if I connect via SSH to a server and want to start a screen session on *that server*, it will create a local screen session instead.

i.e I want a parent (local screen) /children (remote screens) relationship between (or equivalent) instead of multiple SSH connections via local screens

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean 'it will create a local screen sesssion instead'?  When I run screen, then ssh and start a screen session on the remote system, it starts a session on the remote session as expected.

Comment: @yoonix Googled around and found examples with attach/detach and worked my way back. Posted clear answer below. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yep, same idea as with ssh itself.  If you ssh to a host, then ssh to another host and hit `~.` it will detach you from the session closest to you.  Each level you want to pass through you need to add an initial character.  So for closing a nested ssh session you would `~~.`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

Notice the @local vs @remote

user@local:$> screen

`<Ctrl-a> c` and a new local window is created

user@local:$> ssh user@remote

user@remote:$> screen

`<Ctrl-a> a c` and a new remote window is created

user@remote:$>

`<Ctrl-a> c` and a new local window is created

Basically `<Ctrl-a> a [your screen command]`  allows you to call the sub-screen

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run screen within another screen, you need to change screen control character combination (by default it's Ctrl + a).

Typically the first (outer) screen would be controlled with "Ctrl+a" (default), ie press "Ctrl+a" then "?" or "c"

Start screen within the screen (inner) with alternative control character, ie:

```
screen -e^Xx
```

Then you'd press "Ctrl+x" then "?" or "c" to operate inner screen.

Comment: You don't need to change the control character.  If you need send a command two levels deep you just press `CTRL-A A`, and then whatever you want to the far system.  It is a pain though.

Comment: Depends on the pain, but you are right

Comment: Both great answers!  Maybe update your answer to mention both solutions and then it can be accepted?